# Java Applet adding thread makes while loop infinite

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics, applet, awt

I am trying to make a program that generates 25 random ovals then draw a ball and make it bounce, I got it somewhat done, I generated the ovals and I got the ball to move but when I added the thread it kept repeating the draw oval loop, I get somewhat why this is happening but I have no idea how to fix it.

Basically my program should:

1. draw 25 random sized ovals on random locations within the border - **completed**
2. draw a ball and make it move - **completed**
3. make the ball bounce - not done but I know how to do it

but it keeps repeating step one.

this is my code that I have written, oh and I have to use applets right now its part of the course please don't suggest I use swing or something else:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class As4B extends Applet implements Runnable 
{

    public int x, y;
    public int width = 854;
    public int height = 480;
    public int border = 20;
    public Image offscreen;
    public Graphics d;


    public void init()
    {
        setSize(width,height);
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        offscreen = createImage(width,height);
        d = offscreen.getGraphics();
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
        while(true)
        {
            x ++;
            y ++;
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    public void paint(Graphics gfx)
    {
        d.setColor(java.awt.Color.black);
        d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        d.setColor(java.awt.Color.green);
        d.fillRect(0 + border, 0 + border, (width - (border * 2)), (height - (border* 2)));
        genOval(25, d);

        d.setColor(Color.gray);
        d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        gfx.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);

    }
    public int random(int low, int high)
    {
        int answer =(int)((Math.random()*(high-low))+ low);
        return answer;
    }
    public void genOval(int amount, Graphics f)
    {
        int ranWidth, ranHeight, ranX, ranY, red, blue, green;
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 25)
        {
            green = random(0,255);
            blue = random(0,255);
            red = random(0,255);

            f.setColor(new Color(red,green,blue));

            ranWidth = random(30,400);
            ranHeight = random(30,200);
            ranX = random(0 + border, ((width - border)- (ranWidth)));
            ranY = random(0 + border , ((height - border)- (ranHeight)));

            f.fillOval(ranX, ranY, ranWidth, ranHeight);
            i++;
        }   
    }

    public void update(Graphics gfx) {
        paint(gfx);
      }
}
```

Comment: Why use AWT in the 3rd millennium?  We have Swing now.

Comment: its part of the programming course I am taking.

Comment: *"its part of the programming course I am taking."*  ..in 1999?  Tell your instructors to join us in the 3rd millennium.  There are good reasons for doing so, most notably that people who used AWT Components are few and far between, and have likely forgotten what they once knew about it.

Comment: *"oh and I have to use applets right now its part of the course please don't suggest I use swing or something else:"*  You are aware of the Swing based `JApplet` right?

Comment: `repaint();`  Note that this should be called from the Event Dispatch Thread.  Not to put too fine a point on it, but Swing offers `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)` that ensures that happens.  AWT ..doesn't offer any in-built way to ensure that.

Answer (score 0):

Your genOval() method has no persistent backing.  Every time repaint() is called (by your thread), the paint() method is called, and this generates new locations for the random ovals.  You need to create a persistent source for that information, like so:

```
List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();
public void init() {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        int green = random(0,255);
        int blue = random(0,255);
        int red = random(0,255);

        colors.add(new Color(red,green,blue));

        ranWidth = random(30,400);
        ranHeight = random(30,200);
        ranX = random(0 + border, ((width - border)- (ranWidth)));
        ranY = random(0 + border , ((height - border)- (ranHeight)));

        rectangles.add(new Rectangle(ranX, ranY, ranWidth, ranHeight));
    }
}

public void genOval(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        Color color = colors.get(i);
        Rectangle rectangle = rectangle.get(i);
        // Draw using color & rectangle
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that repaint() calls the paint method. But I don't see how this will fix the problem if everything in my paint keeps getting redrawn, to clarify the problem, random ovals keep generating in the background while my ball is moving. What I want to do is only generate 25 ovals, clear the screen then make my ball move without any ovals.  If I take repaint() out of my while(true) it will do that but then the ball will not move.

Comment: If you want to make the ovals disappear completely, you can just use a flag like `shouldDrawOvals`, and set it to false when you don't want to draw them.  Just remember that the `paint()` method WILL be called every 50 milliseconds, so you have to make sure you're drawing the right stuff each time.